# -bash: ./prog_name: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-construction, g++

Say the program name is algo_graphs.c.

And I compile it using `g++ -m32 -c -g -O3 algo_graps.c` and supposing that there are no compiler errors. What could be causing this error:

> -bash: ./prog_name: No such file or directory

After I run `./algo_graphs` on terminal?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `-o [NAME]` option to set the executable name. For example :

```
g++ algo_graps.c -o executableName

./executableName
```

Or try `ls` to see the name of this one. By default, UNIX executable are called `a.out`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you don't tell the compiler to name your executable program `algo_graphs`. If you don't tell the compiler what to name the output file, it will name it `a.out`.

So you have two ways to solve your problem:

1. Use `./a.out`
2. Tell the compiler what to name your file: `g++ -m32 -c -g -O3 algo_graps.c -o algo_graphs`

In the second case, I added the parameters `-o algo_graphs`. The `-o` tell the compiler that the next argument is the name of the output file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following commands for compilation: g++ ../src/Libxml2Example.cpp -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2
Now it works fine.Thanks